# How to setup VPC security groups to allow interaction between 2 ECS Docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-security-group

So I have Grafana running on one ECS container and Prometheus running on another each with their own security group. Both are contained within the same VPC and due to the IP change if a container restarts, I don't want to hardcode the IPs in the security groups allowing access to each other. I'd rather just allow inbound/outbound from the other security group respectively. Grafana runs on port 3000 and Prometheus runs on 9090 so I've tried a combination of inbound and outbound rules over those ports on both security groups but to no avail.

Rules I've tried on Prometheus SG:
`Inbound TCP 9090 GrafanaSG as source | Inbound TCP 3000 GrafanaSG as source | Outbound TCP 9090 GrafanaSG as dest | Outbound TCP 3000 GrafanaSG as dest`

Rules I've tried on Grafana SG:
`Inbound TCP 9090 PromSG as source | Inbound TCP 3000 PromSG as source | Outbound TCP 9090 PromSG as dest | Outbound TCP 3000 PromSG as dest`

I have the base outbound rule allowing all traffic/all ports/ all protocols so the specific outbound rules shouldn't be necessary but tried for sanity sake.

Comment: You surely can designate the source of a Security Group's inbound rule as another Security Group.

Comment: "I'd rather just allow inbound/outbound from the other security group respectively." Then do **exactly** that. "I've tried a combination of inbound and outbound rules over those ports on both security groups but to no avail." Show what you have tried! How can we point out what you are doing wrong if you don't explain what you did?

Comment: @MarkB edited for more information. If I allow access to Prometheus over 9090 from Grafana's public IP everything works smoothly but that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: If you have to allow the public IP, then you have configured your system wrong. You need to configure the systems to communicate over the private IP, and then allow the security group IDs in the security group rules. Right now you are using public IP so the traffic is going out of the VPC, to the Internet, and then back into the VPC, which is removing the security group ID association.